# Performing the button action in MFMessageComposeViewController with custom button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have contact list and I want to send an sms using `MFMessageComposeViewController` and perform action through my custom button without opening the `MFMessageComposer`.I written the action in this method
 `- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result`,but the `MFMessageComposer` is displaying.So only tell me how to do without displaying the `MFMessageComposer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to do this. You either use MFMessageComposer and then the only thing you can customize comes AFTER the composer finishes its work (via the "didFinishWithResult" delegate method) or you implement your own composer (not recommended). What you are doing is implementing a method that comes after the mail composer is done, which is not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer